# Compare one subgroup vs all others in user-friendly way

Tags: tableau-api

I want workbook readers to be able to select different values of a variable to change a chart comparing that subgroup vs. all others grouped together.

For instance, using the Superstore sample data, I can create this chart comparing the percentage of sales by category, by region:

[image: regional breakdown]

I want the user to be able to specify a region and see a comparison of that region's sales distribution vs. all other regions combined.  For instance, I can create a calculated field to group into Central. vs all others, using:
`IIF([Region] = "Central", "Central", "Others")`, which I can use to make this chart:

[image: central vs others]

But I want the user to be able to specify the region to compare (Central, East, South, West) to others.  This approach hard-codes the comparison.  How can I make this something the user can click around on to explore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first create a parameter, specifying "Allowable values" = "List" and then using "Add from Field" and selecting Region, like this:

[image]

Right-click on the parameter (I called it RegionCompare) and select Show Parameter Control. The user will then be able to click around.

Then create a calculated field called **Selected_Region** defined as:

```
IIF([Region] = [RegionCompare], [RegionCompare], "Others")
```

Then place **Selected_Region** on the Rows shelf and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks!  Both of these worked, the latter one is much easier when there are many options.  If you don't mind I will edit in more detail to this answer and emphasize that simpler option.